# firebase database value do not update

Tags: angularjs, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

```
//var ref= new Firebase("https://loginsystem-1ab0d.firebaseio.com/users").child("users");
var ref=firebase.database().ref();
//ref.child('users/' + uid);
var list=$firebaseArray(ref);
console.log(ref);
list.$add({
    date:Firebase.ServerValue.TIMESTAMP,
    regUser:regUser.uid,
    firstname:$scope.firstname,
    lastname:$scope.lastname,
    email:$scope.email
}).then(function(ref){
    var id=ref.key;
    console.log("record is added with id: "+ id);
    list.$indexFor(id);
});
```

may be problem in ref variable, cant figure out what's problem in it.
all dependencies are correct

Comment: need to put more effort into explaining issues as per [ask]

Answer (score 0):

Your first console.log (ref) will not work. You need to wait for the data to load using AngularFire using the $loaded function. However, I'm assuming this is what the issue is as I can't fully understand your exact issue.

Comment: oh yes yes and i also found out that it's a firebase version issue. btw thanks for your comment

Comment: Hope this solved your problem. Please accept the answer if this is the case.

Comment: No, it was actually firebase version issue.